# Add new column to a HuggingFace dataset

Tags: python, numpy, word-embedding, pyarrow, huggingface-datasets

In the dataset I have 5000000 rows, I would like to add a column called 'embeddings' to my dataset.

`dataset = dataset.add_column('embeddings', embeddings)`

The variable *embeddings* is a numpy memmap array of size (5000000, 512).

But I get this error:

> ArrowInvalidTraceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 dataset = dataset.add_column('embeddings', embeddings)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 486         }
> 487         # apply actual function
> --> 488         out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 489         datasets: List["Dataset"] = list(out.values()) if isinstance(out, dict) else [out]
> 490         # re-apply format to the output
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 404             # Call actual function
> 405
> --> 406             out = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 407
> 408             # Update fingerprint of in-place transforms + update in-place history of transforms
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in add_column(self, name, column, new_fingerprint)
> 3346             :class:`Dataset`
> 3347         """
> -> 3348         column_table = InMemoryTable.from_pydict({name: column})
> 3349         # Concatenate tables horizontally
> 3350         table = ConcatenationTable.from_tables([self._data, column_table], axis=1)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/table.py in from_pydict(cls, *args, **kwargs)
> 367     @classmethod
> 368     def from_pydict(cls, *args, **kwargs):
> --> 369         return cls(pa.Table.from_pydict(*args, **kwargs))
> 370
> 371     @inject_arrow_table_documentation(pa.Table.from_batches)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_pydict()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib._from_pydict()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.asarray()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.array()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/array.pxi in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/error.pxi in pyarrow.lib.check_status()
>
> ArrowInvalid: only handle 1-dimensional arrays

How can I solve, possibly in an efficient way, since the embeddings array does not fit the RAM?

Comment: it's crazy that we are in 2023 and still this issue exists.

@albero Did you find a solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 4):

```
from datasets import load_dataset

ds = load_dataset("cosmos_qa", split="train")

new_column = ["foo"] * len(ds)
ds = ds.add_column("new_column", new_column)
```

and you get a dataset

```
Dataset({
    features: ['id', 'context', 'question', 'answer0', 'answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3', 'label', 'new_column'],
    num_rows: 25262
})
```

Comment: This code snippet doesnt address the problem and wont solve it. See the other solution further down

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're trying to add a column, but the data you are passing is a 2d numpy array. `arrow` (the library used to represent datasets) only supports 1d numpy array.

You can try to add each column of your 2d numpy array one by one:

```
for i, column in enumerate(embeddings.T):
    ds = ds.add_column('embeddings_' + str(i), column)
```

> How can I solve, possibly in an efficient way, since the embeddings array does not fit the RAM?

I don't think there's a work around the memory issue. huggingface datasets are backed by arrow table, which have to fit in memory.

Comment: This answer is the actual solution for the problem. The highest scoring one is too generic for this case

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue. It's sad that we are in 2023 and there is still this issue but fortunately, this worked for me.

> ## Add a new column to a dataset
>
> ```
> def add_new_column(df, col_name, col_values):
>     # Define a function to add the new column
>     def create_column(updated_df):
>         updated_df[col_name] = col_values  # Assign specific values
>         return updated_df
>
>     # Apply the function to each item in the dataset
>     df = df.map(create_column)
>
>     return df
> ```

Then, you may call the function like this:

> ```
> import datasets as ds
>
> dataset =  ds.Dataset.from_dict({"column_1": ["value1", "value2"],})
> new_values = [value3, value4]
> updated_dataset = add_new_column(dataset, "column_2", [str(val) for val in new_values])
> ```

**Note:** Please ensure that the size of the new column (A.K.A)

> len(new_values)

is equal to the size of the existing number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

For a dataset loaded from a parquet file, this code worked

```
data['train'].add_column(name="id", column=[i for i in range(len(data['train']))])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was facing this error while adding a column that had TF-IDF representations (2d `ndarray`) of the text sequences.

All I did was:

```
df_encoded['train'].add_column("tf_idf_repr", tf_idf_feats.tolist())
```

It needs a list of lists. This worked!