# Add new column to a HuggingFace dataset inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dataset, tokenize, huggingface

I have a tokenized dataset titled, `tokenized_datasets` as follows:

[image]

I want to add a column titled `['labels']` that is a copy of `['input_ids']` within the features. I'm aware of the following method from this post [Add new column to a HuggingFace dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70064673/add-new-column-to-a-huggingface-dataset):

`new_dataset = dataset.add_column("labels", tokenized_datasets['input_ids'].copy())`

But I first need to access the Dataset Dictionary. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
def new_column(example):
    example["labels"] = example["input_ids"].copy()
    return example

dataset_new = tokenized_datasets.map(new_column)

KeyError: 'input_ids'
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, can you add information, such as which dataset you are loading?

Comment: Yes. It is the `ablam/gcode` dataset on HuggingFace.

Comment: It's bad taste to paste _code_ as images on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the two options below:

```
# first option
def new_column(example):
return {"labels" = example["input_ids"]}

# second option
def new_column(example):
    example["labels"] = example["input_ids"]
    return example

dataset_new = tokenized_datasets.map(new_column)
```

Comment: So apparently, the issue was referring to `dataset_new = dataset.map(new_column)` which is why `'input_ids'` was not recognized. Changed it to `tokenized_datasets.map(new_column)` in my post and code which worked but I did not get rid of `copy()`